# Probability distribution of derivative of function of random variable

Tags: functions, derivatives, random-variables

The calculation of probability distribution of a function of random variable is a well established theory and there are general rules on how to go from the distribution of r.v. to the distribution to the function of that r.v.

However, I am wondering if there are something similar to the case of the function derivative? To be more spefici, if $X \sim \pi(x)$ we can (theoretically) find always a  distribution of $Y=f(X)$. But can we find the distribution of the derivative, i.e. $Z=f'(X)$?

I looked for the information of the net, but in vain. Probably because this is not so trivial as a simple function. But maybe there are some (hidden) publications on this matter? 
Surely, when you know the analytical expression of the function you'll know how the derivative looks like and can simply apply the same theory for the distribution of the function of random variable. I am now interested in such a case.

Comment: ?? Apply what you can do to the function $f'$.

Comment: @Did Could you elaborate more? Not sure if understood what you mean.

Comment: You said you know the distribution of $g(X)$ for every $g$, try $g=f'$.

Comment: @Did Yes, probably that would be the general way to handle this. Didn't think about it at first.